# Python Tkinter Text Output

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a Truth Or Dare game with Tkinter. I get this error:

```
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment
```

When executing this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Truth or Dare")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500,height=350)
canvas.create_text(250, 20, text="Truth Or Dare", fill='red', font=('Helvetica', 20))
text = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='Test!')

def spm():
    canvas.delete(text)
    spillere = ['Niels','Astrid']
    p1 = random.choice(spillere)
    p2 = random.choice(spillere)
    x1 = random.randint(0,3)
    s1 = ['skal spise kage','sig huj ud af vinduet'] # En udfordring til en spiller
    s2 = ['kan du lide kage?','har du nogensinde danset step?'] # Et spørgsmål til en spiller
    s3 = ['skal sige hej til','skal sige huj til','skal spise kage med'] # Noget med en anden spiller
    s4 = ['vil du spise kage med','vil du spise kage med'] # Et spørgsmål om en anden spiller
    while True:
        if p1 == p2:
            p2 = random.choice(spillere)
        else:
            break
    if x1 == 0:
        text = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s' % (p1, random.choice(s1)), font=('Helvetica', 15))
    elif x1 == 1:
        text = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s' % (p1, random.choice(s2)), font=('Helvetica', 15))
    elif x1 == 2:
        text = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s %s' % (p1, random.choice(s3), p2), font=('Helvetica', 15))
    elif x1 == 3:
        text = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s %s?' % (p1, random.choice(s4), p2), font=('Helvetica', 15))


btn = Button(tk, text="Klik!", command=spm, width=50,height=5,font=('Helvetica' , 15))
btn.pack()
canvas.pack()
```

I want the string to be displayed on my canvas when a button is pushed and get a new string displayed when pushing the button again without having two strings in the same spot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `text` as a global value. Otherwise, the interpreter thinks that `text` is local, and gets confused when you refer to it in `canvas.delete(text)` before you assign to it in your `if` suite.

```
def spm():
    global text
    #...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

text inside the spm function is locally scoped and is not the same as the global text variable declared right before the function

I always find it better to make gui enviroments work off of a class, i changed the text variable assigments to id, as canvas.create_text returns the id of the canvas that was acted on, not any actual text value. You'll find by leveraging the class, it will work.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Truth or Dare")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500,height=350)
canvas.create_text(250, 20, text="Truth Or Dare", fill='red', font=    ('Helvetica', 20))
class Window(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='Test!')

    def spm(self):
        canvas.delete(self.id)
        spillere = ['Niels','Astrid']
        p1 = random.choice(spillere)
        p2 = random.choice(spillere)
        x1 = random.randint(0,3)
        s1 = ['skal spise kage','sig huj ud af vinduet'] # En    udfordring til en spiller
        s2 = ['kan du lide kage?','har du nogensinde danset step?']
        s3 = ['skal sige hej til','skal sige huj til','skal spise kage me d'] # Noget med en anden spiller
        s4 = ['vil du spise kage med','vil du spise kage med']
        while True:
            if p1 == p2:
                p2 = random.choice(spillere)
            else:
                break
        if x1 == 0:
            self.id = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s' % (p1, random.choice(s1)), font=('Helvetica', 15))
        elif x1 == 1:
            self.id = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s' % (p1,random.choice(s2)), font=('Helvetica', 15))
        elif x1 == 2:
            self.id = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s %s' % (p1, random.choice(s3), p2), font=('Helvetica', 15))
        elif x1 == 3:
            self.id = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='%s %s %s?' % (p1, random.choice(s4), p2), font=('Helvetica', 15))

window = Window()
btn = Button(tk, text="Klik!", command=window.spm,     width=50,height=5,font=('Helvetica' , 15))
btn.pack()
canvas.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use text as variable name:

```
text = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='Test!')
```

should become(for example):

```
mytext = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='Test!')
```

Comment: But this changes the logic of the program - now when you click the button a second time, it doesn't erase the text on the canvas before writing more text.